# Show that, $\lvert\mathbb P(A\cap B)-\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)\rvert \le \dfrac{1}{4}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space, show that for $A,B\in\mathcal A$
>
> $\lvert\mathbb P(A\cap B)-\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)\rvert \le \dfrac{1}{4}$

If $A, B$ are independent then the inequality is correct (LHS is 0). If not how can we express this dependency ?

Does it attain its maximum, if $\mathbb P(B)$ is 1 ?

Comment: Answer to the followup "Does it attain its maximum, if $\mathbb P(B)$ is 1 ?": Absolutely not! If $P(B) = 1$, then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$ and the LHS is again $0$.

Comment: It will attain its maximum if $B=A^c$ and $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with:

$x=P\left[A\cap B\right]$, $y=P\left[A^{c}\cap B^{c}\right]$, $a=P\left[A\cap B^{c}\right]$
and $b=P\left[A^{c}\cap B\right]$ where $a,b,x,y\geq0$ and $a+b+x+y=1$.

Then: $$\left|P\left(A\cap B\right)-P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)\right|=\left|x-\left(a+x\right)\left(b+x\right)\right|=\left|xy-ab\right|\leq\max\{xy,ab\}$$

Here $xy\leq\frac{1}{4}$ as a consequence of $x,y\geq 0$ and $x+y\leq 1$. Under these conditions $xy$ achieves its maximum if $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$.
Likewise $ab\leq\frac{1}{4}$ and we are ready.

Its maximum is attained if $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $A\in\{B,B^c\}$.